# hi, my realtime database rules are not making sence, i want the int to only be allowed to go up by 1, not down, nor up more than 1

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

here is my rules code, the code updates in unity every time the user gets +1 point. the rules need
to make it that points can only be updated by +1 (basically , currentPoints = newPoints +1).
in unity i would write it as:

```
if (currentPoints < newPoints) currentPoints++;
```

now how do i state my rules to stick to that so my code cant be hacked/edited by a hacker to give
them +1000 points at a time instead of +1 on the database.

```
{
"rules": {
 "users": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
   "$userId": {
    ".write": "$userId === auth.uid",
      
      "points": {
        ".validate": "newData.isNumber()",
          ".write": "data.val() == null && newData.val() == 1 || newData.val() === data.val() + 1"},
              "username": {
                ".validate": "newData.isString()"}
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your current rules, you get caught out by [cascading security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authorization):

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      // any logged in user can read another user's data
      ".read": "auth != null",

      "$userId": {
        // a user can modify any of their own data
        ".write": "$userId === auth.uid",

        "points": {
          // asserts points is a number
          ".validate": "newData.isNumber()",

          // this next rule is ignored when $userId === auth.uid - read/write rules cascade!
          // if $userId !== auth.uid, ANYONE can write to this location as long as points is first set to 1 or is increased by 1
          ".write": "data.val() == null && newData.val() == 1 || newData.val() === data.val() + 1" 
        },

        "username": {
          // asserts username is a string
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With your current rules, as long as I am logged in, I can get the value of `/users/someUserId/points`, increase it by 1, and then set the new value to `/users/someUserId/points`. Arguably, the only person who should be able to increase a user's points is the user who owns that score.

To fix this, you need to remove the `".write"` rule (which causes this bug) and move it's logic into `".validate"`:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      // any logged in user can read another user's data
      ".read": "auth != null",

      "$userId": {
        // a user can modify any of their own data
        ".write": "$userId === auth.uid",

        "points": {
          // asserts points is a number and is correctly increased by 1
          ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && ((data.val() == null && newData.val() == 1) || newData.val() === data.val() + 1)",
        },

        "username": {
          // asserts username is a string
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** With the `".read": "auth != null"` rule for `/users`, make sure that any private user data, e.g. emails, phone numbers, etc are not under `/users` - they should be moved into a different tree called `/privateUserData` (or similar).

Comment: Thanks , that helps understanding a lot. now my issue is when the user logs in with 1 point. i get this error in unity: Failed to register task with System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.Database.DatabaseException: Internal task faulted ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.FirebaseException: This client does not have permission to perform this operation.

Comment: That's a permission error of some kind deserving of it's own separate question. Make sure that you aren't reading/writing data before the login task has finished and that you are writing to that user's own score.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. ill go through the firebase RTDB scripts in my project and make sure im not doing that.